# How to login to same session with same user using xrdp and tigervnc-server?

Tags: centos, vnc, session, gnome2

I have `Centos 6.4` with `Gnome2`, I'm accessing it through its `xrdp (Version 0.5.0)` and `Xvnc TigerVNC 1.1.0` services.
The clients machine are an `Android` tablet and a `Windows 7` PC, these are using different screen resolutions for the connection. I close the connections with `gnome-session-save --kill`.

I saw [an article](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4168) recommending to rebuild xrdp for this purpose another [thread](http://xrdp-devel.766250.n3.nabble.com/Xrdp-devel-XRDP-connect-to-an-already-existing-session-started-from-a-diferent-machine-td3868393.html) suggests that a newer version would do it, but I would stick to this version if there is a configuration that will do what I am after: to have the same session if same user logs in. Although it would be a big compromise, but even forcing the sessions to the same size and limiting the available sessions to 1 session per 1 user would do it if it works as expected.

Can somebody suggest me a workaround for this or I have no options left, have to [grab](http://www.unix.com/red-hat/223039-how-install-xrdp-centos.html) and try a newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving to have the same Desktop on the Android that was configured on the PC is to log out with Android, log in with PC, do the necessary configurations and then log off and

`service xrdp restart`

This will make the other devices with different resolutions to load in the icons, etc., the session as the last session exited.

For a CentOS 6.4 with i386 architecture I couldn't find an rpm for xrdp with version >0.6. At my workplace it is discouraged to compile from source, so the update option isn't an option really.